# Android Relative Layout alignment

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, textview, android-relativelayout

I have a form. Which has few rows. Every row has two text views side by side. the left textview is static and the right textview is dynamic. based on the text of right textview(it may be any number of lines) the origin of the next row must depend as shown below. I am using relativelayout and writing in xml. How can i do it.

[image]

Note: I dont want to use grid or table layout due to some limitation.

Comment: have u checked my answer

Comment: @kaushik I know it but I have many fields, I am not interested in that way

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(xxxxx);

Comment: which rule should i add?

Comment: 1. params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, left_top_view_id);
2. params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, left_bottom_view_id);     params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BOTTOM_OF, right_top_view_id);

Answer (score 0):

Fix the left side textview static and draw the remaining items from java code.

Comment: If you are not restricting the width and height with hard-coded values you can go with xml otherwise go through java

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Static Text 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Multiple line\nDynamic text 1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstLinearLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Static Text 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="Multiple line\nDynamic text 2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```